# Adjust Image on button

Tags: image, python-2.7, button, tkinter

How can I adjust an image to a button in Tkinter?

Actually i have this :

```
originalImg = Image.open(currentphotofolderPath + file)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(originalImg)
Button(photoFrame, image = img, borderwidth=0, height = 200, width = 200)
```

The problem the image does not adjust to the button with 200x200

I don't want to resize the image with `PhotoImage.resize()`

Comment: you would have to resize the image first, the button cannot resize the image for you, setting its size manually will effectively just crop to a section of the image. you will have to resize the image with either `Image.resize` or `PhotoImage.resize`

Comment: Ok... so can we resize an image but keep properties, let me explain:
for example my image is 300x600, i don't want to set it to 200x200, but to 100x200.
The problem is i don't know the dimensions of my image ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a couple of choices, the zoom function as posted by Billal, or you create a resize function:

```
def Resize_Image(image, maxsize):
    r1 = image.size[0]/maxsize[0] # width ratio
    r2 = image.size[1]/maxsize[1] # height ratio
    ratio = max(r1, r2)
    newsize = (int(image.size[0]/ratio), int(image.size[1]/ratio))
    image = image.resize(newsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return image
```

which will then resize the Image (not the PhotoImage) to the biggest possible size while retaining the aspect ratio (without knowing it beforehand)

note that the resize method should use less memory than the zoom method (if thats an important factor)

Answer (score 2):

The [`zoom()`](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter.PhotoImage-class.html#zoom) function should fix your issue:

> Return a new PhotoImage with the same image as this widget but zoom it
>   with X and Y.

Adding the code line below before instantiating the `Button()` widget should be helpful:

```
originalImg = Image.open(currentphotofolderPath + file)
originalImg.zoom(200, 200)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(originalImg)    
Button(photoFrame, image=img, borderwidth=0, height=200, width=200)
```

Comment: Thx for replyi have an error with your code :


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/projet-python-photo/Sources/GUI/main.py", line 180, in <module>
    originalImg.zoom(200, 200)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: zoom`


This is my import


`from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk`